# How to make this FtpWebRequest code faster?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I've written this to check whether the filename in a table column exists on ftp server directory if it exists then update (using update query) the column Isexists with value `1` else keep as it is.

I'm using DataTable to read each row (filename) then making FtpWebRequest all time to check
whether the file exists of not.

This way `CheckIfFtpFileExists(string fileUri`) getting call for the numbers of times is equal to the no. of rows in the DataTable.

Is there any way I can make FTP auth. only once and then call the function.

Any suggestion How can I improve my code to increase the speed of.

```
namespace FTP_File_Check
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DMSTG;Data Source=.";



   string sql = @"SELECT full_file_name from Intellitrack.S_Sr_att_Delta_Consolidated_28082012 where Isexists=0";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
           conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {


                    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DMSTG;Data Source=.");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    if (CheckIfFtpFileExists("ftp://myftpaddressgoeshere.com/0708/" + row[col].ToString()))
                    {
                      // Found File Exists
                        cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Intellitrack.S_Sr_att_Delta_Consolidated_28082012 
                                       SET Isexists = 1 
                                         where full_file_name='" + row[col].ToString() + "'";
                        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

                        sqlConnection1.Open();

                       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlConnection1.Close();

                    }


                }

            }

    }

    public static bool CheckIfFtpFileExists(string fileUri)
    {

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fileUri);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuserid", "mypassword");
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.ConnectionGroupName = "file";
            request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 8;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = false;

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;


            try
            {

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (FtpStatusCode.NotLoggedIn == response.StatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to ftp server");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Environment.Exit(99);

                }
                else
                {

                    if (FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable == response.StatusCode)
                    {

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

        return true;
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: are the files all in the same remote directory?

Comment: @paul yes on remote server in one directory.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you could use `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails`, this would give you a list of all the remote files with one call. You could store this in a `List<string>` and then just check each row of the database against this list.